# Java xPath/DOM - When importing a node into a document, xPath query is unable to find new node (and sub node)

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I am trying to import a node into a 'new' DOM Document and then execute xPath queries on the newly imported nodes.  The XML that I'm working with has no namespaces.  I have followed the standard procedure to create a document, as shown:

```
    Document newDoc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
          DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
          newDoc = builder.newDocument();   
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
      // Parser with specified options can't be built
      pce.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and to import the nodes...

```
    // nodeToImport is a node from a prior xPath search (part of a node set)
    Node docToRunXPathOn = newDoc.importNode(nodeToImport, true);
```

Later, when I try to run an xPath query such as

```
    XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

    if (docToRunXPathOn != null) {
        try {
            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//version_id/text()");
            return (String)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
    }
```

The evaluation returns an empty string.  A sample XML is below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Version>
       <version_id>51312</version_id>
       <description>Some Description</description>
    </Version>
```

The solution that I've employed is to serialize the DOM into a string, and then immediately parse that string to re-build the structure as a new DOM.  This seems incredibly inefficient and backwards - what am I missing with this import and xPath?  I had thought it might be because the node's parent and such are not being set properly, but when I did the clone/adopt method (or adopting after importing) the same behavior is seen.

Any answers/explanations/suggestions/thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Document's importNode() only imports the node to the document - it does not add it as a child node to an existing node. You have to do that separately. Something like:
    newDoc.getFirstChild().appendChild(newDoc.importNode(nodeToRunXpathOn, true));

Comment: I misspoke in my post... replace adopt with append. I will try your suggestion tomorrow, because although I had appended a node to the doc, I didn't use the method getFirstChild()

Comment: Implemented your suggestion aryn.galadar, no luck.  Still pulling an empty result from the xPath.  Is there some inner working of xPath/DOM that relies on some metadata that isn't being updated on the import of the node?  If it makes any difference, I am using the basic Java implementation of everything - no imported parsers or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote small testcase for reproduce, and after import XPath found "51312", maybe it helps.

```
public class ImportNodeTest {
@Test
public void testImportNode() throws Exception {
    final Document newDocument = createDocument();
    final Element importedElement = getExistedNode();

    Node docToRunXPathOn = newDocument.importNode(importedElement, true);
    newDocument.appendChild(docToRunXPathOn);

    XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//version_id/text()");
    System.out.println(expr.evaluate(newDocument, XPathConstants.STRING));
}

private Document createDocument() {
    Document newDoc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        newDoc = builder.newDocument();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        // Parser with specified options can't be built
        pce.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newDoc;
}


private Element getExistedNode() {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(new File("xml.xml"));
        return document.getDocumentElement();
    } catch (Exception pce) {
        throw new RuntimeException(pce);
    }

}
```

}